# Can we compose two empty mappings?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, function-and-relation-composition

I am reading "Set Theory and General Topology" by Takeshi SAITO (in Japanese).

This book contains the following problem:

> Let $X$ be a set.
> Let $F, G : \text{Map}(X, X)\times\text{Map}(X, X)\to\text{Map}(X, X)$ be mappings such that $F(f, g) = f\circ g$ and $G(f, g) = g\circ f$.
> What is the necessary and sufficient condition on $X$ that ensures $F=G$?

The author's answer for this problem is here:

> The necessary and sufficient condition on $X$ that ensures $F=G$ is $|X|\leq 1$.
> If the number of elements of $X$ is less than or equal to $1$, then $\text{Map}(X, X)=\{\text{id}_X\}$.
> So, $F=G$.
> Let $a, b\in X$ and $a\neq b$.
> Let $a, b : X\to X$ be constant mappings such that $a(x) = a$ and $b(x) = b$ for any $x\in X$.
> Then, $F(a, b) = a\circ b = a \neq b=b\circ a=G(a,b)$.
> So, $F\neq G$.

Let $X=\emptyset$.
In this case, I think we cannot compose two empty mappings, so we cannot define $F$ and $G$.
So I think the necessary and sufficient condition on $X$ that ensures $F=G$ is $|X|= 1$.

Am I wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with the composition $\emptyset \stackrel{f}{\to} \emptyset \stackrel{g}{\to} \emptyset$?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can compose two empty mappings. Let $e$ be the empty map. Then $e\circ e$ is, by definition, the function which maps all elements $x\in\emptyset$ to $e(e(x))$. Since there are no $x\in\emptyset$ in the first place, the empty map does this vacuously: it maps all of the necessary $x$ (explicitly: none are necessary) in the prescribed way.

Comment: While technically correct, I don't think using $\emptyset$ for both the domain/codomain of the function **and** the function itself is a good idea here. (But for educational purposes, I hope the OP can appreciate that this is literally the definition of the empty map, as it is a subset of $\emptyset \times \emptyset = \emptyset$).

Comment: @DanRust: On second thought, you're right, it's a very technical kind of correct, which isn't always the best kind of correct. I renamed it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am confused.

Comment: @tchappyha: Maybe another way to think about it: is there any element in the domain which is *not* mapped in the way required of compositions? There is not, since there are no elements in the domain.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thank you very much.